# Using Qt STL between applications built with QtCreator and Visual Studio

Tags: c++, qt, dll, stl

I am working on a software project where the interface is designed with Qt Creator. This application links to some dynamic libs built in Visual Studio.

I have built Qt from source with Visual Studio, but since the libraries in Qt Creator are built using MinGW, **is there any danger of passing Qt STL objects between the application and the DLL,** considering the fact that they are both built with different compilers?

The only thing I can think of is conflicts between debug and release.

More info: the only Qt classes that the DLL will use is QString, QVector, and QMap.

**EDIT:**
PS: What about the standard stl? Any concerns mixing the binaries between MinGW and MSVC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. There is no standardized C++ [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), and the ABIs of GCC and MSVC are certainly not compatible -- the ABIs aren't even compatible between different versions of MSVC. Build your entire library with the compiler that you want to use.

Comment: So simply put, an application written in Qt Creator cannot call on any DLL compiled by MSVC?

Comment: @rem45acp An application written in Qt Creator can call *some* code in a DLL compiled by MSVC.  A simple way is to call functions that use a standard convention like PASCAL or C. ( google Extern "C"). In my opinion DLLs shouldn't pass around fully built (or randomly packed) data anyway.

Comment: This is one of the major drawbacks of STL-based code on Windows in my opinion.  You basically can never expose methods which return or work with STL containers unless you want to tie yourself down to a specific compiler toolchain.  I don't know if that's just an intrinsic problem for templates or not though.  It certainly complicates getting unmanaged C++ code into a managed C# application.  So perhaps it is by MS design... ;)